# Erro ao executar o comando yarn start/ npm start

Tags: react, yarn

Assim que executo o comando create-react-app e faz criação do projeto. no final quando eu vou executar o comando "yarn start". segue o seguinte erro:

```
yarn run v1.22.4
warning package.json: No license field
error Command "start" not found.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

Ja tentei várias coisas como, deletar a pasta node_modules, deletar o yarn.lock, deletar o package.json, desinstalei e instalei o node de novo. Não sei o que aconteceu, pois um dia atrás eu estava rodando o comando normalmente.

Comment: Tenta  rodar o comando ```yarn``` na pasta do projeto (apenar o yarn, depois o comando completo)

Comment: Como é um comentário à minha resposta, não crie uma nova resposta para a pergunta, comente na minha resposta que já fez isso e ainda assim não funcionou. Aproveita e edita a sua pergunta com mais essas informações e inclusive adicione o package.json, uma vez que a mensagem de erro aponta para ele.

Comment: Eu exclui da maquina as pastas npm/yarn e quando executei o comando create-react-app, funcionou! Acho que havia alguma problema com aquelas pastas. Assim que eu criei uma nova aplicação react, foi instalado na maquina uma nova pasta npm e desde então, não tive mais problemas. Agradeço todas as sugestões! Muito obrigado!

Comment: Ola!
Pode parecer bobo, mas eu estava tendo esse mesmo problema e tudo o que eu fiz foi fechar o programa (vscode), e reabri. Me certifiquei de que estava dentro da pasta correta do projeto (web) e fiz o processo de novo. Deu certo. No meu caso foi apenas falta de atencao. Espero que seu problema seja tao simples quanto foi o meu. Abraco!

Comment: Eu estava com o mesmo erro, tentei de algumas formas , mas resolveu quando reiniciei o VsCode.

Answer (score 3):

Nesses casos, procure incluir o passo a passo executado na sua pergunta. Pela descrição do problema, o mais provável é que vc tenha criado o projeto e não tenha entrado na pasta do dele.

Seguindo a documentação do react:

```
yarn create react-app my-app
cd my-app
yarn start
```